# mvc in asp.net doesnt satisfy programmers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC4 in Visual Studio and I have many questions about it. My first statement about MVC is that MVC's Model doesnt do what I expected. I expect Model to select and return the data rows according to the needs.

But I read many tutorial and they suggest me to let Model return ALL the data from the table and then eliminate the ones I dont need in the controller, then send it to the View.

here is the code from tutorials

MODEL

```
public class ApartmentContext : DbContext
{
    public ApartmentContext() : base("name=ApartmentContext") { }
    public DbSet<Apartment> Apartments {    get; set;   }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ApartmentContext db = new ApartmentContext();
        var apartments = db.Apartments.Where(a => a.no_of_rooms == 5);
        return View(apartments);
    }
```

Is this the correct way to apply "where clause" to a select statement? I dont want to select all the data and then eliminate the unwanted rows. This seems weird to me but everybody suggest this, at least the tutorials I read suggest this.

Comment: These are the best tutorials I've seen for MVC: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4-building

Comment: I am so confused. To a newbie, it gets so confusing

Comment: Your question is not about MVC but about EF.

Comment: I upvoted your comment but I agree and disagree with you. I believe it is a problem with the way MVC designed in .net. or maybe there isnt enough resources for developers to see the whole picture. I am still working hard to learn MVC in .net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well which ever tutorial you read that from is wrong (in my opinion). You shouldn't be returning actual entities to your view, you should be returning **view models**. Here's how I would re-write your example:

```
public class ApartmentViewModel
{
    public int RoomCount { get; set; }
    ...
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new ApartmentContext())
    {
        var apartments = from a in db.Apartments
                        where a.no_of_rooms == 5
                        select new ApartmentViewModel()
                        {
                            RoomCount = a.no_of_rooms
                            ...
                        };
        return View(apartments.ToList());
    }
}
```

> Is this the correct way to apply "where clause" to a select statement?

Yes, this way is fine. However, you need to understand what's actually happening when you call `Where` (and various other LINQ commands) on `IQueryable<T>`. I assume you are using EF and as such the `Where` query would not execute immediately (as EF uses delayed execution). So basically you are passing your view a query which has yet to be run and only at the point of where the view attempts to render the data is when the query will run - by which time your `ApartmentContext` will have been disposed and as a result throw an exception.

```
db.Apartments.Where(...).ToList();
```

This causes the query to execute immediately and means your query no longer relys on the context. However, it's still not the correct thing to do in MVC, the example I have provided is considered the recommended approach.

Comment: I tried to use your code but I had an exception - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ConstructionProject.Models.ApartmentModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ConstructionProject.Models.Apartment]'.

Comment: @ayilmaz I forgot to add the `ToList()` call on the apartments query - see update.

Comment: I disagree with "returning actual entities is wrong". Most of the official tutorials were teaching that. That was part of the beauty - simple and fast scaffolding. There certainly are use cases, where you have to care about security of some properties, but It doesn't mean, that you have to map every single entity to viewmodel.

Comment: I added the ToList() but still gives this exception "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConstructionProject.Models.ApartmentModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ConstructionProject.Models.Apartment]'."

Comment: @ayilmaz you need to update your view to accept `ApartmentViewModel` as it's model, not the raw entity type i.e. `@model ConstructionProject.Models.ApartmentViewModel`.

Comment: @Dampe it doesn't make sense though, are you exposing information to the view which it doesn't nor will bother to render so it's a waste of potential bandwidth right away. And then on top of that you need to attempt retain that information between posts - a lot of entity specific information is lost throughout that lifecycle. It's *much* cleaner to go via a ViewModel and only expose/retain the information the view needs and then deal with mapping that back to the entity server-side - so in my opinion it's wrong, I will update to clarify that.

Comment: _"Well which ever tutorial you read that from is wrong."_ - all official ASP.NET MVC templates and tutorials work with a `DbContext` directly in the controller, returning entities instead of models. Even worse, they call entities models everywhere.

Comment: I am so confused :) thanks for your help people but I am more confused now

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah I have updated just to clarify that it's my opinion and that's not to say you *can't* return entities to your view I would just recommend not doing it :)

Comment: @James Good points. I just wanted to point out that your statement was quite bold and it could lead some people to conclusions like "every entity must have its view model", that could escalate to 1:1 view models for even the simplest entities :)

Comment: @Dampe yeah it was a fair point to make hence the update. Personally I don't think entities have *any* business in the views, but it does appear to be the way the official tutorials are promoting the usage of them (and I can see why) - however, in reality I don't think they work quite as well as they think they do.

Answer (score 1):

In our project, we will add a Data Access Layer instead of accessing Domain in controller. And return view model instead of Domain.

But your code, you only select the data you need not all the data.

If you open SQL Profiler you'll see that's a select statement with a where condition.

So if it's not a big project I think it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see these tutorials but are you sure it's loading all the data? It looks like your using entity framework and entity framework uses [Lazy laoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). And Lazy loading states:

> With lazy loading enabled, related objects are loaded when they are
>   accessed through a navigation property.

So it might appear that your loading all the data but the data itself is only retrieved from SQL when you access the object itself.

Comment: This has not to with related entities, but with [querying data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj573936).